# Get external page title

Tags: php, ajax

I have a task.

One input:

> input type='text' id='url' name='url'

One button:

> button id='go'

and one div.

User writes a site in that input and onclick i must show title of that site

How can i do that ?

Comment: This question is off topic for serverfault. It may be on topic for Stackoverflow but check their [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and search their site before asking there. They also don't like give me teh codez type questions much though.

Answer (score 1):

From what you told me, here's some code.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['go'])) {
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET" />
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" /><br /><input type="submit" name="go" id="go" />
</form>
<?php
} else {
$url = $_GET['url'];
$file = file($url);
$file = implode("",$file);

if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i",$file,$m)) {
    print "The title of $url is <b>$m[1]";
} else {
    print "The page doesn't have a title tag";
}
}
?>
```

This downloads the file into the PHP memory and gets the information between the title tags.